# How to definitively reject/replace a binary in the new iTunes Connect when button missing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm writing my own question and answer here, because there are dozens of them on stackoverflow, and all have different answers, none of which worked for me.

So, it's been many months since the new iTunes Connect launched, and for a lot of people it's **still** impossible to reject your own binary so you can replace it, for example if you upload a binary, the status changes to "waiting for review" and then you realise you have a bug so want to upload a new binary.

For many people, there are just no buttons/links/anything on the screen that allows you to modify the binary.

I have my own answer which I'll post now, but it's a total hack, so if anyone else has a sure fire and cleaner way of dealing with this nightmare of a system that Apple has forced on us, please post!

**EDIT**

Sadly, this didn't work, the old build was released even though everything on iTunes Connect indicated the new one was up for review. More details in the comments throughout this post.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to get around the problem ...

Upload a new binary, to do this you need to change the build number .. in the plist, this is "Bundle version" NOT "Bundle versions string, short", although you can change that if you want also.

Since everything, and I mean everything, about the app submission process is f***** then you probably wont get confirmation from Organizer that the binary was submitted, but it probably was.

Wait a short time, log into iTunes Connect, go to your app, click on the "pre-release" tab, you should see your new binary in there, it may still say "processing", if so .. I would wait until that stage has completed before continuing.

### NOW THE HACK

In the "Versions" tab, there *should* be a blue plus icon right beside the word "Build". For me, there wasn't.

USING CHROME: Go to the "Versions" tab and scroll down to build. Right click on build and choose "inspect element".

Expand the div with class "section" and then the h1 with class "ng-binding". In here you will see the word "Build", right below this is a link (a href), it has three classes in the html ... "addIcon ng-binding ng-hide". Double click here and you can edit. Delete ng-hide. BOOM, the plus icon will appear on the web-page, you can now click and choose your new build, then save.

What. A. Complete. Joke.

### DISCLAIMER

My app is waiting for review, I cant guarantee that Apple wont turn around and approve the old binary, but everything I can see in iTunes Connect suggests that it's the newer binary that is waiting to be reviewed .. so I'm hopeful. I'll update once the review is complete.

Comment: Thanks for this... it worked for me. Post back here when you find out if yours worked :)

Comment: I changed the version per instructions, but I got a rejection from Apple yesterday saying that the app crashed... with the bug I fixed in the newer upload.

Comment: Apple finally approved my update, the build number shown is the NEWEST version of the app .. so all looked good .. I released it .. and my users have received the original one I rejected, which is broken, so now I have tens of thousands of users using a broken app. It took Apple 19 days to approve the last update and now I need to begin again. I'm so close to just dropping support for Apple completely.

Comment: Just to add some more info to this, in lots of the other stackoverflow posts about this problem people were saying "just hover over the build number under builds and the reject button will appear", that didn't happen for me, but now when I was uploading a new build .. BEFORE submitting it for review, if I hovered over the build number the reject button did appear, however as soon as I submitted the app for review, it stopped showing

Comment: And some more info .. I now need to reject a build again, I just logged in and now there is big, bold section at the very top of the page that says "You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." .. the last three words of this are a link! I clicked the link, and the binary rejected exactly as it should. The mind boggles.

Comment: Steven -- You should update your original post saying that it didn't work, since the OLD build was released instead of the NEW build. Edit: Also, I'm very sorry to hear it didn't work for you and that the broken release went out to all your users.

Answer (score -1):

You can also reject the binary using a similar method to Stephen:

Search for "modal for dev reject" in the html. Remove the class "ng-hide" from that. Accept when prompted to reject the build.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I hit reject, but it still said waiting for review, still showed my old build, and still stubbornly refused to let me add a different build.

Comment: Refused to let you add a build from where? You add a build using XCode, when reject (using my method), and click '+' to add a new build (using Stephens hack if the '+' doesn't exist)

Comment: Yeah -- I had done all your steps but didn't have the '+' so I had to use Steven's hack.